# Delete a dynamic row with confirmation box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to delete a row by clicking delete button in a bootstrap modal:

```
$('#delete').click(function() {
    $('.dlt').closest('tr').remove();
});
```

If I use `.dlt` means all rows is getting deleted.Because, I am getting data dynamically. How can I delete only current row?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/otz2ojm1/

Comment: try my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Use **this** instead of class name and use **.dlt** on click function to get all click event.

2) on click event show the model using `$('#confirm').show()` function

3) And capture the event by id delete or cancel and do operation by respectively.

```js
var roleList=[{
"sNo"     :"1",
"roleName":"Designer",
"edit"    :"Edit",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
},
{
"sNo"     :"2",
"roleName":"Developer",
"edit"    :"Edit",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
},
{
"sNo"     :"3",
"roleName":"HR Dept",
"edit"    :"Edit",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
},
{
"sNo"     :"4",
"roleName":"Project Manager",
"edit"    :"Edit",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
}
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    empRoles();
     $('.dlt').click(function(){
          old = $(this);
          $('#confirm').show();
            $('#delete').click(function(){
             old.closest('tr').remove();
              });
    });
});
function empRoles(){
 for(var i=0;i<roleList.length;i++)
    {
     var table='<tr><td>'+roleList[i].sNo+'</td><td>'+roleList[i].roleName+'</td><td><button class=" edit "><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>'+roleList[i].edit
                +'</button><button class="dlt " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'+roleList[i].dlt+'</button></td><tr>';
     $('#roleListTable').append(table)
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
   
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead class="roleListTableHead">
       <tr>
        <td>S.NO</td>
        <td>ROLE NAME</td>
        <td>ACTION</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="roleListTable">
       
      </tbody>   
     </table>
       </div>
       <div id="confirm" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure?  Do you want to delete this record?
           <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning  btn-xs" id="delete">Delete</button>
           <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
             </div>
```

use **this** instead of class name and use **.dlt** on click function to get all click action.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   empRoles();
   $('.dlt').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: you just replace my code with your existing snippet it will work fine as you expected

Comment: I am asking when I click delete in bootstrap modal then only my record get deleted.Not in table itself.

Comment: can you check my updated answer and let me know the questions if anything have .@krish

Comment: I don't want to use `confirm()` I added two buttons in nootstrap modal right?Using that only I have to delete my record.

Comment: run my snippet it will work perfect as you expected @krish

Comment: don't forgot to upvote and accept it as  accepted answer . @krish

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you should hook the `click` event to the `.dlt` elements, then use the `this` keyword within the event handler to reference the clicked element. `closest('tr')` will then find the element you need to remove.

Also note that you may need to use a delegated event handler as you are building the table content dynamically. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    empRoles();
    $('#roleListTable').on('click', '.dlt', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/otz2ojm1/2/)